# How to dynamically loop through webpages using nightmareJS and cheerio?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio, nightmare

```
var scrape = new Nightmare({
        show: false
    })
    .goto(urlOb.url)
    .wait(1000)
    .evaluate(function() {
        return document.body.innerHTML;
    }).end().then(function(html) {
      if (html == undefined) {
        console.log('========================');
        console.log('html not there!');
        console.log(arg);
        console.log('========================');
        return;
      }

  var $ = cheerio.load(html);
```

I need for this scrape to jump to the next page once it's done scraping the first page. I've been working with the .click(), .visible() function in addition to other nightmareJS native functions, but I keep coming up short. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: So, basically you want to scrap an entire website right?

Comment: @DavidR yes exactly. I am able to scrape everything I need. Only issue, I need to scrape each page and I want to do this dynamically to make it scalable